# If $f( \log_2 x)-f( \log_3 x) \le \log_5 x$ then $\log_5 \left( \frac{3}{2} \right) \int_0^1 f(x)dx \le 2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuous in $x_0=0$, and Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. If $f(0)=0$ and $f( \log_2 x)-f( \log_3 x) \le \log_5 x, \forall x>0$, prove that $\log_5 \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)\cdot \int_0^1 f(x)dx \le 2$.

Well, an idea is to integrate the given inequality between 1 and 2, but a change of variable will give us something nice just for $\int_1^2 f (\log_2 x) dx$, and not for $\int_1^2 f(\log_3 x)dx$. So, this idea fails!

Another way I tried is to denot $\log_2 5=a$ and $\log_3 5 =b$. Now, put $x=5^t$ in the given inequality and obtain $f(ta)-f(tb) \le t \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$. The conclusion becomes: $\left( \frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a} \right) \int_0^1 f(x)dx \le 2$.

But I don't know how to use the inequality from hyphotesis. It can be written in this form: $f(t) \le \frac{t}{a} -f \left( t \frac{b}{a} \right), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, but, nothing. Can somebody help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: Another idea would be to plug in $x=3/5$ in the given equation, but then you have $\log_5(3/2)\ge \ldots$ (i.e. bigger than something) and you want to show that $\log_5(3/2)\cdot\int \le \ldots$ (i.e. less than something). Are you sure you have all inequalities the right way? (just in case)

Comment: Yes! That's the statement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a>b>0$ and 
$$ f(ta)-f(tb)\leq t $$
for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then we have:
$$ f(t)\leq\frac{t}{a}+f\left(t\frac{b}{a}\right)\leq\frac{t}{a}+\frac{bt}{a^2}+f\left(t\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)\leq\ldots\leq\frac{t}{a-b}+f(0)=\frac{t}{a-b}  $$
from the continuity of $f$ in zero and from $f(0)=0$. By integrating the previous inequality over $[0,1]$, with the choices $a=\log_2 5,b=\log_3 5$, we get:
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\,dt \leq \frac{1}{2(a-b)} = \frac{1}{2(\log_2 5-\log_3 5)}=\frac{\log 2\log 3}{2\log 5(\log 3-\log 2)}=0.58346\ldots$$
that is way better than the required inequality to prove.